# Use a NSString to display in another string?

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsstring

I need to be able to show if the switch is on or off in a alert along with other details, all of the details display just fine but when I try to add the notificationStatus string it gives me an error. "Use of undeclared identifier 'notificationStatus'"

```
-(void) procrastinationNotificationSwitchOnOrOff {

    if (_procrastinationNotificationSwitch.on) {
        _notificationOnOffLabel.text = @"Procrastination Notification On";
        NSString *notificationStatus = @"NOTIFICATION ON";
        NSLog(notificationStatus);
    }
    else {
        _notificationOnOffLabel.text = @"Procrastination Notification Off";
        NSString *notificationStatus = @"NOTIFICATION OFF";
        NSLog(notificationStatus);
    }
}


-(void) presentMessage:(NSString *)message {
    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Class Stuff" message:message delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
    [alert show];

}

-(void) notificationStatus:(NSString *)stat {
   NSString *status = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", stat];

}


-(IBAction)returnKeyButton:(id)sender {
    [sender resignFirstResponder];

    NSString *classNameString = self.className.text;
    NSLog(classNameString);
    NSString *assignmentTitleString = self.assignmentTitle.text;
    NSLog(assignmentTitleString);
    NSString *assignmentDescriptionString = self.assignmentDescription.text;
    NSLog(assignmentDescriptionString);
    NSString *totalStrings = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@ %@ %@", classNameString, assignmentTitleString, assignmentDescriptionString, notificationStatus];
    NSLog(totalStrings);

    NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];
    dateFormatter.timeZone = [NSTimeZone defaultTimeZone];
    dateFormatter.timeStyle = NSDateFormatterShortStyle;
    dateFormatter.dateStyle = NSDateFormatterShortStyle;

    NSString *dateTimeString = [dateFormatter stringFromDate: dateTimePicker.date];
    NSLog(@"Alarm Set Button Tapped : %@", dateTimeString );
    [self presentMessage:totalStrings];
}


- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    [_procrastinationNotificationSwitch addTarget:self action:@selector(procrastinationNotificationSwitchOnOrOff) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a local variable notificationStatus in your method procrastinationNotificationSwitchOnOrOff. You also have notificationStatus. You don't have a property or instance variable notificationStatus.

Add a property notificationStatus. Get rid of the method notificationStatus. Always read and write notificationStatus using self.notificationStatus. Problem solved.

Comment: is there any way to add line breaks to a string in an alert?

Answer (score 0):

I think you're confusing things by having the method

```
-(void) notificationStatus:(NSString *)stat {
   NSString *status = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", stat];

}
```

Would be better off making it a local variable and if you want manipulate it, use getters and setters.